# How to parse retrieve value from a json string field in Redshift/SQL

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I have a row that looks like this:

---

id | json_list | expected_result

"1" | [{"id":"1", "text":"text1"},{"id":"3", "text":"text3"}] | "text1"

"2" | [{"id":"2", "text":"text2"},{"id":"3", "text":"text3"}] | "text2"

---

I want to retrieve the "text" field based on the id column. How can I achieve that in AWS Redshift? I know Redshift has some json functions and it needs to be paired with some kind of loop condition, but I wasn't sure if it's possible in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know , If I have understood your question correctly or not.
Because the data is a bit confusing.

Id column value - 2
Your Json value -  `[{"id":"1", "text":"text1"},{"id":"3", "text":"text3"}]`
Expected Result - `text1`

**Solution ->**

**Step 1** - Iterating through various JSON Elements

`select json_extract_array_element_text('[{"id":"1", "text":"text1"},{"id":"3", "text":"text3"}]',1)`

[image]

**Step 2** - Parsing key,Value Pairs in a particular JSON Element

`select json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text('[{"id":"1", "text":"text1"},{"id":"3", "text":"text3"}]',1),'text')`

[image]

So, Suppose I have a table -

```
create table dev.gp_test1_20200731
(
id int,
json_list varchar(1000),
expected_result varchar(100)
)
```

Inserting Data -

```
insert into dev.gp_test1_20200731
values
(1,'[{"id":"1", "text":"text1"},{"id":"3", "text":"text3"}]', 'text1'),
(2,'[{"id":"2", "text":"text2"},{"id":"3", "text":"text3"}]', 'text2')
```

How does the data look like -

[image]

This is how the query would be -

```
select json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(json_list,1),'text')
from dev.gp_test1_20200731
where id = 2
```

Result -

[image]

But, It is not a good practice of storing JSON's in Redshift.

Documentation on why  - [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html)